# Mac: How to install Windows 10 Preview on Parallels

Tags: macos, parallels, windows-10-preview

I'm trying to install Windows 10 preview on Mac OS X with Parallels, but the ISO file is not recognized by Parallels. The ISO is not defect, I've checked the Hash.

Comment: have you tried to to manually drag the ISO into the browse for ISO window?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have had to proceed anyway. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag the ISO, it says it doesn't recognise it - Click Proceed anyway...

Mine is plodding away nicely right now - prompted by this question, in fact; though I wasn't going to bother...

*This is assuming you have Parallels 10 - can't say how 9 or lower would behave*

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem installing the WindowsPreview in Parallels 9.

**Solution**

1. Clone an existing Windows 8.1 VM
2. The bit-levels of the VM and the downloaded `WindowsTechnicalPreview.iso` have to be the same (64-bit>64-bit or 32-bit>32-bit respectively ).
3. Mount the `WindowsTechnicalPreview.iso` in the VM and install with `setup.exe`. You will be asked if you want to keep your private files or wipe all.

Windows 8 and 7 should work as well.